# EE3 Is there any simple way to implement infinite loop scrolling

Tags: ee3, loop

Tried this tutorial not working http://iamjustinlong.com/blog/single/implementing_infinite_scroll_in_your_expressionengine_site/ when I click to next it goes to url instead of appending entries, no error on console.log.

Wondering if any one had luck on infinite loop entries lately. I have simple news channel:

```
<div class="articles">
  {exp:channel:entries channel="news" dynamic="no" show_future_entries="yes"}
    <div class="article">
      <h1>{title}</h1>
    </div>
  {/exp:channel:entries}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used jscroll before http://jscroll.com/ it seems to work fine. Here's some sample code:

```
<div class="infinite-scroll">
    {exp:channel:entries channel="news" dynamic="no" show_future_entries="yes"}
    <p class="item">{title}</p>
    {paginate}
    {if next_page}
    <a href="{auto_path}" class="jscroll-next">Next</a>
    {/if}
    {/paginate}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
</div>

<script>
$('.infinite-scroll').jscroll({
    loadingHtml: '<img src="loading.gif" alt="Loading" /> Loading...',
    padding: 20,
    nextSelector: 'a.jscroll-next:last',
    contentSelector: '.item'
});
</script>
```

Comment: Nice it worked. thx